# Android: touch events methods explanation

Tags: android, touch-event

I'm a little bit confused about touch events method, in particular these 4 method:

- `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`
- `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`
- `ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`
- `ViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)`

I have underestood these methods are used to manage touch events across nested view. It's right? Can anyone explain me (or pass a good tutorial) how these methods should work together? Android official documentation is it not so clear for me about this topic.. Thank you.